Is there a way to get all finally blocks across all threads to run when handling Ctrl+C in a Console Application
I have a console app that I want to be able to exit via ctrl+c. In my codebase/external libraries there are types which absolutely need their Dispose/Close() methods called for cleanup.
The suggested question in the comments is about how to trap the ctrl+c event. I already know that I can do this:
Console.CancelKeyPress+= ... obj.Close()/obj.Dispose()
The issue is that I have to remember to do this before every using block.
Is there a general way - ideally ONE event handler for CancelKeyPress that I register in the root for the whole application that somehow forces finally blocks across all threads to run?

This question is similar to: How do I trap Ctrl+C (SIGINT) in a C# console app?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Luuk I know of Console.CancelKeyPress...the thing is how to achieve it in a cleaner fashion.

Do you really need to do this for every disposable object? Besides, shouldn't the cleanup be done by the object itself if this is necessary?

@shingo I can obviously do some hacky facade that I shouldn't forget to register on top of the normal finally. Just curious if somebody comes up with something better.

Can you provide an example of your using block and the CancelKeyPress before it?

@IvanPetrov Please [edit] your question to ask in a way that it doesn't sound opinion-based. The term "a better way" is subjective and such questions are off-topic. Also add more details of the content of the finally blocks and using blocks you have and the threads you are dealing with. Also explain how much control you have over the threads and libraries you are using.

@Progman from your comments, it seems that there isn't an easy way...was looking for something like Environment.Exit(magicExitCode)...

or ...throwing an exception from another thread/joining it.

Why wouldn't the using block work by itself? I'm confused about your code, why isn't cleanup working already?

@Charlieface because when we terminate via ctrl+c finally blocks are not executed. We are left with the eventhandler...I thought there might be some way to gracefully shutdown the applications from one event handler - allowing all threads to run the finally blocks...seems there isn't one.

Perhaps the way to go here is to switch your code to using the async/await approach, and create a CancellationTokenSource that you trigger from CancelKeyPress; now you have one central well-known pattern that can flow (via CancellationToken) through your code. Any inbuilt/library async methods will typically already support cancellation, and it isn't hard to implement in your own code, if needed, either by explicit periodic testing, or by registering as a callback.

sounds good, but what if the token is not checked for 2,3 seconds?

@IvanPetrov if you need to interrupt, that's when you'd use a scoped using var reg = token.Register(...) with a callback that can proactively break the thing that is running for those 2,3 seconds. The point being that you can then enregister close to individual operations.

Fleshing out the suggestion from Marc Gravell's answer, I wanted a bit different behavior than Register with CancellationTokens:
public static class CancelKeyCleanupExtensions
{
    private const int DEFAULT_WAIT_MILLISECONDS = 3000;

    /// <summary>
    /// If no cleanupaction is provided the Dispose() method
    /// of the instance will be called for cleanup
    /// </summary>
    public static ICancelKeyPressRegistrationToken GetCancelKeyPressRegistration<T>(this T obj, Action<T> cleanup = null, int milliSecondsWait = DEFAULT_WAIT_MILLISECONDS)
    where T : class, IDisposable {

        var cancelKeyRegistration = new CancelKeyPressRegistrationToken<T>(obj, cleanup, milliSecondsWait);
        lock (s_listLock) {
            s_waitList.Add(new WeakReference<CleanupWaiter>(cancelKeyRegistration));
        }
        return cancelKeyRegistration;
    }

    public interface ICancelKeyPressRegistrationToken : IDisposable
    {
        void ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }

    private abstract class CleanupWaiter
    {
        public async Task<bool> TryWaitForCleanup() {
            try {
                await CleanupTask.WaitAsync(WaitTime);
                return true;
            }
            catch {
                return false;
            }
        }
        public abstract TimeSpan WaitTime { get; }
        public abstract Task CleanupTask { get; }
    }


    private static object s_listLock = new();
    private static List<WeakReference<CleanupWaiter>> s_waitList = new();
    private static ManualResetEventSlim s_cancelKeyPressed = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);

    static CancelKeyCleanupExtensions() {
        Console.CancelKeyPress += Console_CancelKeyPress;
    }

    private static void Console_CancelKeyPress(object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e) {
        s_cancelKeyPressed.Set();

        lock (s_listLock) {
            var liveObjects = s_waitList
                .Select(x => { x.TryGetTarget(out var target); return target; })
                // here we have a strong reference guaranteed to be live for the rest
                // of the method
                .Where(x => x != null)
                .ToList();

            if (liveObjects.Count == 0) return;

            var waitingTasks = new List<Task>();
            foreach (var item in liveObjects) {
                waitingTasks.Add(WaitandLogOperation(item));
            }

            // TODO: might not be needed
            var maxWaitTIme = liveObjects.Max(x => x.WaitTime);
            var globalFailsefe = maxWaitTIme + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

            Task.WhenAll(waitingTasks)
                .Wait(globalFailsefe);
        }

        async static Task WaitandLogOperation(CleanupWaiter waitForCleanupObject) {
            var successfulWait = await waitForCleanupObject.TryWaitForCleanup();

            // Log
            if (successfulWait) {
                Console.WriteLine("xxxxxxxxx CLEANUP COMPLETE xxxxxxxxxx");
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("xxxxxxxxx CLEANUP NOT FINISHED xxxxxxxxxx");
            }
        }
    }

    private sealed class CancelKeyPressRegistrationToken<T> : CleanupWaiter, ICancelKeyPressRegistrationToken
        where T : class, IDisposable
    {
        T _instance;
        Action<T> _cleanupAction;
        int _milliSecondsWait;
        TaskCompletionSource _disposingtcs;

        public CancelKeyPressRegistrationToken(T instance,
            Action<T> cleanupAction = null,
            int milliSeconds = DEFAULT_WAIT_MILLISECONDS) {

            ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(instance);
            _instance = instance;
            _cleanupAction = cleanupAction;
            _milliSecondsWait = milliSeconds;
            _disposingtcs = new TaskCompletionSource(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
        }

        // will go to the Dispose
        // since class is used in an using block
        public void ThrowIfCancellationRequested() {
            if (CancelKeyCleanupExtensions.s_cancelKeyPressed.IsSet)
                throw new OperationCanceledException();
        }

        public override TimeSpan WaitTime => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_milliSecondsWait);
        public override Task CleanupTask => _disposingtcs.Task;

        int _disposingState = 0;

        public void Dispose() {
            // execute only once
            if (Interlocked.Increment(ref _disposingState) > 1) return;

            try {
                if (_cleanupAction != null) {
                    _cleanupAction(_instance);
                }
                else {
                    _instance.Dispose();
                }
            }
            finally {
                _disposingtcs.TrySetResult();
            }
        }
    }
}

The use would be:
using var consumer = consumerBuilder.Build();
using var cancelCleanupRegistration = consumer.GetCancelKeyPressRegistration(
    c => c.Close(), 4000);
while (true) {
    cancelCleanupRegistration.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

The main benefit is that it's a cooperative cancellation process using the same control flow for cleanup.  and not callbacks running concurrently on another thread at unknown and possibly inopportune times.
